# How to initialize the variables of a pb file in tensorflow without accompanying ckpt files?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-datasets

I have a simple pb file, without any ckpt file. I would like to (randomly)initialize all the weights of the pb file and save the the initialized weights as ckpt file. I could not find any way to do it. global variable initializer just threw no variables to save

Answer (score 0):

The Model can be saved in `.pb format` in three ways. Using `tf.saved_model.simple_save`, `tf.saved_model.Builder.save` or `estimator.export_savedmodel`.

To answer your question, you can restore the `.pb model` using the function, `tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess,[tag_constants.TRAINING],Export_Dir)`.

Then, you can restore the Weights (you should remember the name corresponding to `Weights Tensor`) using the below code:

```
with graph2.as_default():
        with tf.Session(graph=graph2) as sess:
            # Restore saved values
            print('\nRestoring...')
            tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess,[tag_constants.SERVING],path)
            #Specify the correct `Weights_Tensor_Name`
            Weights_Var = graph2.get_tensor_by_name('Weights_Tensor_Name:0')
```

After that, you can save the Weights to .checkpoint files using the below code:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver({"Weights_Var": Weights_Var})
```

But if you just want to save a `Random Tensor` (with name `Weights`) into Check Points File, you can generate a Random Tensor using the function, `tf.random.uniform` and then can save it using the code below:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver({"Weights_Var": Weights_Var})
```